# Wordpress .htaccess How to avoid redirect loops for images?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, redirection

I'm configuring Redirects from a Html static website to Wordpress, I'm doing it manually in the .htaccess file and for some other rules I'm using [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/.)

I have added these rules to my .htaccess:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.htm|\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.htm|\.html)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
..
```

They work fine redirecting old html documents to the new wordpress installation without file extension.

I have problems trying to add the needed redirection for images.
I have tried adding this rule but I get redirection loop when I try to access .jpg files:

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.jpg
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.jpg)$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
```

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images were in a subdirectory such as `images` the solutions is simple

```
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*\.jpg)$ wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the images are in random locations or in the root.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
RewriteRule ^(.*\.jpg)$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The point is, your `RewriteRule` is matching again after you redirect into the wordpress directory. (It matches **ANY** jpg). You have to find a way to NOT match the **new** wordpress based files.